# MailMessage properties not accepting parameter variables

Tags: c#, mailmessage

For some reason, when trying to initialize the properties `From`, `Subject`, and `Body` for a MailMessage object I can't use variables from the method parameters.

Ex - Doesn't work:

```
public static void MailToEML(String email, String subj, String body)
{
    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage
    {
        From = new MailAddress(email),
        Subject = subj,
        Body = body
    };
```

(Rest of method irrelevant)

Ex - Works

```
public static void MailToEML()
{
    String email = "some@email.com";
    String subj = "Subject";
    String body = "Contents";

    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage
    {
        From = new MailAddress(email),
        Subject = subj,
        Body = body
    };
```

I've tried with `List<String>`, `String[]`, and `String` parameters, none of them seem to work, but when they are initialized inside the method, it works flawlessly.

Error when trying with parameters:

> System.FormatException: 'The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.'

FIXED: Similarily, if `From` is correct, `Subject` will output the same error message, and same with `Body`.
Solution: Appended a \n to `Subject` somewhere else in the code, which the formatting did not agree with, so I just had to remove that

Calling method:

```
public void ExportClicked(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
    Object selObject = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];

    Outlook.MailItem mailItem =
        (selObject as Outlook.MailItem);

    String email;
    String subject;
    String body;

    email = mailItem.SenderEmailAddress;
    subject = mailItem.Subject;
    body = mailItem.Body;

    if (mailItem.Subject == null)
    {
        subject = ThisAddIn.lang[1]; //Array element determines language, not important here
    }

    ThisAddIn.MailToEML(email, subject, body);

}
```

(Just want to mention that I will be making these an array or list if I find a solution)

Comment: I just tested and the first example seems fine. Can we see the arguments passed into the MailToEML() method? Usually if you are missing the '@' symbol in the email it will throw that exception.

Comment: Your code is fine, but the exception is telling you that your email address string is not in a correct format. Please show the code that's calling the method. Also, what do you mean by, *"if `From` is correct, `Subject` won't work"*? You should **always** describe what "won't work" means.

Comment: @RufusL I will edit the question to show you the calling function, but what I meant by that last part, is that if I put a string directly into the email, I get the exact same error message for the `Subject` property.

Comment: @RufusL Also, I also suspected it was something with the e-mail being formatted incorrectly, but I added a MessageBox.Show() to the function (just to visually see the e-mail address) and it was correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around for a while,  I figured out I was making this a lot more complicated than it really was. Instead of several string values, I used a MailItem object.

This is the new MailToEml() method:

```
public static void MailToEML(Outlook.MailItem mail)
{
    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage
    {
        From = new MailAddress(mail.SenderEmailAddress),
        SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
        Subject = mail.Subject,
        Body = mail.Body
    };
```